# QuantLib Python Installation

Tags: python, quantlib

I am trying to install QuantLib Python for Windows as per the instructions on this link; http://quantlib.org/install/vc10.shtml At first the file cstddef was not in the correct path and I had to search it and put it in the correct path. When I Build the Solution again, a new file stddef.h was not being found in Boost and I hatried to search for it in the Boost Folder but I did not find it. I managed to download the stddef.h file from the internet and I put it in the right path and when I Build the Solution again another new file yvals.h (`1>C:\Program Files\Boost\boost_1_64_0\stddef.h(5): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'yvals.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file ql\experimental\math\particleswarmoptimization.cpp)`) was not being found in the Boost Folder again. I did not find this file again in the Boost Folder and when I tried to download it on the internet it is being sold. Can Someone help on how I can have this file or if there is an easier way to do the installation.

Comment: Those files are from the standard library and not from Boost.  Are you sure your Visual Studio installation is working correctly?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2017 and I am not sure if it is the one causing this problem. Which Visual Studio do you recommend me to install?

Comment: It depends on your version of Python. http://quantlib.org/install/windows-python.shtml lists the suggested versions of Visual Studio for each Python version.